# ¿Por qué obtengo error de compilación con una consulta sobre SQLite? (SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1))

Tags: android, sqlite

Siguiendo un tutorial de *androidhive* tengo una aplicación que recibe mensajes a través de `GCM` y además lanza notificaciones `push`. El problema es que los mensajes no se guardan, por lo tanto al cerrar la aplicación se pierde la información, entonces estoy tratando de hacer un `ListView` con la lista de los mensajes recibidos mediante la clase `GCMintentService`, que es la que pienso yo recibe los mensajes en segundo plano.

La idea es insertar el mensaje o mensajes en una base de datos SQLite y mostrarlos en un `ListView` en mi `activity` principal.

Esto es lo que he intentado, pero al probar la aplicación, me salta el mensaje de que su aplicación se ha detenido.

**GCMintentService.java**

El método donde creo yo recibe el mensaje

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);

    ////CODIGO PARA GUARDAR EL MENSAJE EN LA BASE DE DATOS O INSERTAR LOS      DATOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    db.insertMsg(message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

El código que muestra el ListView

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dbcon = new SQLController(this);
    dbcon.open();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Cursor cursor = dbcon.readData();
    String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.IDs, DatabaseHelper.MSG };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ids, R.id.msg };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**SQLcontroler.java**

```
public class SQLController {

    private DatabaseHelper DatabaseHelper;
    private Context ourcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public SQLController(Context c) {
        ourcontext = c;
    }

    public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
        DatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ourcontext);
        database = DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        DatabaseHelper.close();
    }


    //Getting Cursor to read data from table
    public Cursor readData() {
        String[] allColumns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.IDs,
                DatabaseHelper.MSG };
        Cursor c = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }    
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GCM";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "newsTable";
    public static final String IDs = "_id";
    public static final String MSG = "MESSAGE";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + IDs + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + MSG + " STRING)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /////// INSERTAR MENSAJES EN LA BASE DE DATOS
    public void insertMsg(String msg) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("MESSAGE", msg);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

---

Comentando en onMessange TEST

```
  protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);

    ////CODIGO PARA GUARDAR EL MENSAJE EN LA BASE DE DATOS O INSERTAR LOS         DATOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS
 //   DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
   // db.insertMsg(message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

Y este es el LOG de errores al ejecutar la aplicación:

```
01-25 21:48:05.959  20271-20271/pushnotifications.androidhive.com.pushnotifications E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pushnotifications.androidhive.com.pushnotifications, PID: 20271
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pushnotifications.androidhive.com.pushnotifications/pushnotifications.androidhive.com.pushnotifications.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, MESSAGE FROM newsTable
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, MESSAGE FROM newsTable
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
            at pushnotifications.androidhive.com.pushnotifications.SQLController.readData(SQLController.java:38)
            at pushnotifications.androidhive.com.pushnotifications.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: puedes poner el link del tutorial porque hay cosas que yo no hago asi que veo y no se si estan bien, si pones el tutorial mejor, por otro lado que mensaje te sale al cerrarse en el log. Saludos

Comment: Disculpa aqui esta: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Hola, de antemano gracias por la ayuda, comente asi por que sino me manda error de sintaxis y no me deja ejecutar se lo muestro arriba en actualización para que se vea mas claro

Comment: El problema igual es que no se esta creando _id, puede consultar la base de datos, copiandola de sus telefono o emulador, y mirarla con algun programa de SQLite, es posible que se este creando como id

Comment: puede usar este -> http://sqlitebrowser.org/ para mirar si el campo es id o _id para descartar puede mirar por aqui -> /data/data/com.app.package/databases/ o algo asi, tambien puede desintalar la app manualmente y volver a instalarla igual esta usando una db antigua que no se acualizara con el _id

Comment: Prueba de separar el código, primero asegúrate que se lee bien el id de la tabla y después vas poniendo lo de mensajes push

Comment: Hola @Angel Angel desinstale la app y volví a ejecutarla y ya funciona :) muchisimas gracias por la ayuda le dejo puntos

Comment: gracias @Webservice aparentemente ya se soluciono al desinstalar la app del cel y re ejecutarla

Comment: Pongan respuesta  para dejarles votos, y muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Una pregunta: esta forma de almacenamiento y consulta de datos repercutirá de alguna forma le rendimiento a futuro en caso de que sean muchos datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema igual es que no se esta creando `_id`, *(aunque veo que usted lo asigna mediante una variable)* puede consultar la base de datos, copiandola de sus telefono o emulador, y mirarla con algun programa de `SQLite`, es posible que no se este creando como `_id` (por cualquier cosa) puede usar este -> http://sqlitebrowser.org/ para mirar si el campo es `_id` y no `id` u otro, o si este realmenete se esta creando en la `bd` que usted consulta, para descartar puede mirar por aqui -> /data/data/com.app.package/databases/ o algo asi, tambien puede desintalar la `app` manualmente y volver a instalarla, igual esta usando una `db` antigua, que no se esta acualizando con el `_id`.

Comment: La solución mas simple, que no requiere desinstalar la app, es dentro del dispositivo, ir a Configuracion -> Aplicaciones -> Configurar Aplicaciones, buscar tu app y accionar "Borrar datos de aplicación". Esto hace que la próxima vez que inicies la app, se llame nuevamente a onCreate.